# Struts2: reading an array of input into an action

Tags: text, input, struts2

I'm trying to get an array of input into my action class but it always returns null;

Here's the HTML for the input

```
<input class="activityInput" type="text" name="sentdate[" + i + "]" value="1" />
<input class="activityInput" type="text" name="sentdate[" + i + "]" value="2" />
```

and here's the class for the action

```
public class ActivityAction extends ActionSupport{
    private List sentdate;
    public List getSentdate() {
    return sentdate;
    }

    public void setSentdate(List sentdate) {
        this.sentdate = sentdate;
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need the square brackets.

```
<s:textfield name"sentdate" value="1" />
<s:textfield name"sentdate" value="2" />
```

would render the following html

```
<input type="text" name="sentdate" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="sentdate" value="2" />
```

This should populate the 'sentdate' List of your Action.

Answer (score 2):

Struts should populate List but don`t :)
The better solution of this problem is to use String instead List in Struts action class properties.
If you submit form with

```
<input type="text" name="sentdate" value="1" />
<input type="text" name="sentdate" value="2" />
```

you will reseive in "private String sentdate" this: 1,2
and you can split this string with comma delimiter and give you List..

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`<s:select>`](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/docs/select.html) tag.

Answer (score 0):

Is it even making it to the Action? I suggest using an HTTP listener like Fiddler, or IBM Page Detailer, so that you can see what, if anything, is even being sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider a debug statement in your action to see what you get back. I'm thinking something like at the top of your Action:

```
Enumeration parameterNames = request.getParameterNames();
while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
  String currentParameterName = (String) parameterNames.nextElement();
  String[] values = request.getParameterValues(currentParameterName);
  for (String value : values) {
    logger.debug("Parameter " + currentParameterName + " has value " + value);
  } 
}
```

And I think it would be better if you use the real HTML in your sample. The " + i + " thing
is not HTML and I can't see from here how that is rendered to HTML. It's probably allright but I prefer to see the HTML code as the browser sees it.

Comment: h lol. that was my problem. I forgot to change " + i + " to \"" + i + "\"

Answer (score 0):

as Stanimir told even the "value" attribute is not required. Just sending the parameters with the same name is enough. In the serverside we will get the list of string.